# Don't wait for response after sending request to server in java

Tags: java, sql, ajax, spring

I am creating a JSP page which has one Upload button(to upload XLS and later update this data in DB). As soon as user will click on Upload button it will read the XLS file and prepare a list of objects that will be passed to a method (m1(List a)) to execute SQL queries. 
Now the problem is that i have around 100 sql queries in this method(m1(List a)), that takes around 30 min to get completed. 
So I don't want user to wait until this method completes DB process. 
Is there any way i can call my method to update DB and without waiting for the response of this DB operation, i can respond to user that file has been uploaded and DB process has been initiated that will be completed after some time.

Comment: 30 _minutes_? Looks like there is a problem elsewhere to start with... Anyway, the solution here would be to use an `Executor` and submit the db operation to it.

Answer (score 1):

Hand off the work to be done outside of the request-response cycle to an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

```
private void doDatabaseWork(Input input) {
     BackgroundWorkTask task = new BackgroundWorkTask(input);
     executorService.submit(task);
     // since the work is now handed off to a separate pool of 
     // threads, the current HTTP-handling thread will continue 
     // here and return a response to the user
}

public class BackgroundWorkTask implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // put all of your database querying operations in here
    }
}
```

Make sure that, since this is a webapp, you have a way to shut down the ExecutorService when the webapp is stopped - which will also give the ExecutorService a chance to finish any in-progress work before allowing the container to stop.